# Password protect single directory in IIS 8

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8

How can I password protect a single directory in IIS 8 under Windows Server 2012 Standard?

Example: I want to be able to access mysite.com, but when navigating to mysite.com/secured, I want to be prompted for a password for access.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Open your IIS manager and select the directory you want to protect.
- Under the "IIS" section select "Authentication".
- Disable "Anonymous Auth".
- Enable the desired Auth method (usually "Basic Auth") and it will be valid for this directory only.
- Add a User account.

  - Left click directory in IIS, Edit Permissions..., Security, Edit, Add, enter a user from your Active Directory
- Give that user Read, Execute, List Permissions on the directory needed, then login via the newly created user.

  - left click newly added user and check Allow for Full control
- To log in, use the domain username and password (i.e. UN: admin@myDomain.local, PW: p@$$w0rd).

  Note: You can add / remove auth methods @ Role Services window.

---

As an alternative you can code some auth system using serverside languages like PHP / ASP

Comment: Thanks, Solarac. Being new to IIS, I had not noticed that you could select a directory as well and then change the settings. I guess I was having trouble finding it because it was too obvious, and I am used to .htaccess files. Thanks again!

Comment: If 'Basic Auth' is not available in the list, you will need to install it first using Server Manager Add Role and Features.

Comment: What does "add a user account" mean? A windows account?

Comment: Yes @ChrisSmith, this is a **Windows User Account**. You can manage them by right-clicking on the "*Start*" button, then "*Computer Management*", then "*Users and Groups*".